# Can't scrape data from website that loads data via js

Tags: python

I want to scrape data from this website https://app.microacquire.com/startup/BoHpuALvJmNoNWkXY8qtxVMwTyO2/sy8mcXmDyu4LGyXADT11

I have tried finding an API but didn't find one.

When I inspect the network-tab I see that some JS is loading data and the data is added after `<div id="root"></div>`.

I have tried using the requests library in python.
I have tried using Scrappy also.
I can not use selenium as well In selenium i need to setup browser env . and when i deploy the scrapper on aws i need to do many configuration for selenium and other scrapper are written without selenium .

It is returning nothing from `div root`.
It is retuning this document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="" size="" href=/assets/img/favicon.873c75.ico>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon type="" size=180x180 href=/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.5cf5ac.png>
<link rel=icon type=image/png size=192x192 href=/assets/img/android-chrome-192x192.f4283c.png>
<link rel=icon type=image/png size=512x512 href=/assets/img/android-chrome-512x512.abfde3.png>
<link rel=icon type=image/png size=32x32 href=/assets/img/favicon-32x32.2803d9.png>
<link rel=icon type=image/png size=16x16 href=/assets/img/favicon-16x16.1b4454.png>
<meta name=msapplication-TileColor content=#3E50F7>
<meta name=theme-color content=#ffffff>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,900&display=swap" rel=stylesheet>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&display=swap" rel=stylesheet>
<script>!function(e,t,a,n,g){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var m=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],r=t.createElement(a);r.async=!0,r.src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PWTLTGV",m.parentNode.insertBefore(r,m)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer")</script>
<script>!function(e,t,n,c,o,a,f){e.fbq||(o=e.fbq=function(){o.callMethod?o.callMethod.apply(o,arguments):o.queue.push(arguments)},e._fbq||(e._fbq=o),o.push=o,o.loaded=!0,o.version="2.0",o.queue=[],(a=t.createElement(n)).async=!0,a.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js",(f=t.getElementsByTagName(n)[0]).parentNode.insertBefore(a,f))}(window,document,"script"),fbq("init","664023900970575"),fbq("track","PageView")</script>
<noscript>
<img height=1 width=1 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=664023900970575&ev=PageView&noscript=1">
</noscript>
<script defer=defer src=/runtime~main.b5c61d.js></script><script defer=defer src=/styles.af3e5e.js></script><script defer=defer src=/2863.3da2c3.js></script><script defer=defer src=/5242.87ddcb.js></script><script defer=defer src=/420.ac7361.js></script><script defer=defer src=/511.dd9bb2.js></script><script defer=defer src=/8875.ed7fec.js></script><script defer=defer src=/8367.35d4f9.js></script><script defer=defer src=/5116.917de7.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9829.5a9bb3.js></script><script defer=defer src=/672.749d36.js></script><script defer=defer src=/5918.d50413.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9804.62405c.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9431.d9d2f2.js></script><script defer=defer src=/5174.4155c6.js></script><script defer=defer src=/7821.c2e33b.js></script><script defer=defer src=/912.416645.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9971.3da150.js></script><script defer=defer src=/8390.f9220b.js></script><script defer=defer src=/349.7ff7a5.js></script><script defer=defer src=/664.d61309.js></script><script defer=defer src=/5414.41231f.js></script><script defer=defer src=/888.2f5182.js></script><script defer=defer src=/7707.e787a4.js></script><script defer=defer src=/3484.fd309c.js></script><script defer=defer src=/446.3592e8.js></script><script defer=defer src=/295.2c25cd.js></script><script defer=defer src=/884.8f8ac9.js></script><script defer=defer src=/7171.cc1d90.js></script><script defer=defer src=/4554.0d1db9.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9151.86d098.js></script><script defer=defer src=/7784.f5ec63.js></script><script defer=defer src=/1239.40b4eb.js></script><script defer=defer src=/1384.5c1672.js></script><script defer=defer src=/6731.beefca.js></script><script defer=defer src=/6189.88159d.js></script><script defer=defer src=/4228.519fc8.js></script><script defer=defer src=/2151.ebda93.js></script><script defer=defer src=/8594.b1f8c6.js></script><script defer=defer src=/4429.961b63.js></script><script defer=defer src=/8270.544883.js></script><script defer=defer src=/7799.a6d8b6.js></script><script defer=defer src=/6885.973a5b.js></script><script defer=defer src=/9177.ae98af.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-9a8b795a.911509.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-743b5ef9.e397d5.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-aede1861.16a305.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-8c6c39d6.e5d158.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-c4c4009f.56c1c7.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-b308cbaf.08bfa4.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-f4988fac.1221f3.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-953ecaf6.053612.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-73aa4e9a.ba467e.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-78ba660c.97dd48.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-8f21d56f.426ded.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-799d6395.3b82b7.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-592e47b8.d1a593.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-42e6843f.036e74.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-78fd58b3.9bf0a3.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-2187c21c.776bbe.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-1040bad5.8b5efc.js></script><script defer=defer src=/main-66b77520.f5045a.js></script><link href=/styles.2f6097.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/main-b308cbaf.2e12a4.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/main-73aa4e9a.fa5769.css rel=stylesheet></head>
<body>
<div id=root></div>
<noscript>
<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PWTLTGV" height=0 width=0 style=display:none;visibility:hidden></iframe>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot scrape dynamic content using requests library.. you would have to simulate a user fir that you could use something like selenium or maybe you could try [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) library

Comment: @mohdsabahat Thank for ans. In selenium i need to setup browser env . and when i deploy the scrapper on aws i need to do may configuration for selenium and other scrapper are written without selenium

Comment: You could just analyze what url's JS is requesting to and then do those requests yourself.

Comment: @trauni Hii , I tried them also but there 10+ Js request and google api request are there and them after one request is made like channel?data   .
when i tried to hit that url it is giving error .
there are lots of attribute are there like sid, guid ,pid and i am unable to find them . 
they are coming from some different diff.. url

Comment: I took a look at it and it seems like it is going to be very hard finding out what values to return. I would suggest using selenium or... find out how to do the requests.

Comment: @trauni only problem with selenium is that is very slow even i made mine to use it .
because i need to made more that 3000 Requests and scrape data from simple page . 
if i use selenium then it will take arround 2-3 Hours.
and i have scheduled the scrapper to run in every 2 hour

Comment: For retracing every argument, you need to get for the requests to work, I would suggest using [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload). It's and good and fast tool for tracing and looking at requests. Make sure to look at a tutorial first as it can be confusing at first. @saharshsolanki